# Join each line from two files as one line using python

Tags: python, string, join

I am trying to join lines of two files as one using python. Can anyone help me out on this:

**File 1:**

```
abc|123|apple

abc|456|orange

abc|123|grape

abc|123|pineapple

abc|123|mango
```

**File 2:**

```
boise

idaho

sydney

tokyo

london
```

Expected Output File:

```
abc|123|apple|boise
abc|456|orange|idaho
abc|123|grape|sydney
abc|123|pineapple|tokyo
abc|123|mango|london

**Code tried so far:**

    from itertools import izip
    with open('merged.txt', 'w') as res:
            with open('input1.txt') as f1:
                    with open('input2.txt') as f2:
                            for line1, line2 in zip(f1, f2):
                                    res.write("{} {}\n".format(line1.rstrip(), line2.rstrip()))
```

I am new to python, is there a simple way to append lines from two files with the separator '|'. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very close, just change the last line to:

```
res.write("{0}|{1}\n".format(line1.rstrip(), line2.rstrip()))
```

Comment: this is the error i am getting:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "App.py", line 6, in <module>
    res.write("{}|{}\n".format(line1.rstrip(), line2.rstrip()))
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: Do you know the exact version of python you are running?  (If you don't know, at the Python prompt type 'import sys' then 'version')

Comment: The version is 2.6.6.

Comment: Your version requires you to number your arguments so put a 0 and a 1 in between the first and 2nd set of curly braces.  Answer updated to reflect this.  2.7+ does not require the indices.

Comment: Thanks Jeff... works fine. unix paste command was more easier actually. Just found out. Just told so that others who read this may benefit. paste -d"|" input1.txt input2.txt > merged.txt

Answer (score 0):

A concise version will be like this

```
file1=[y.strip() for y in open("file01").readlines()] # read all lines
file2=["|"+x.strip() for x in open("file02").readlines()]  #read all lines but add a "|" at begining of line in file2 
mergedfile=zip(file1,file2) #combine lines
merged_file=open("a_new_file","w")
for line in mergedfile:
    merged_file.write(line[0]+line[1]+"\n") #combine lines
merged_file.close() #close "a_new_file"
```